# how to identify whose response i am getting on hitting same end point n number of times?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am hitting an api end point multiple time. how can i identify that the response is for nth api request.
let's assume user hits on upload button thrice.how to track each hit request.

Comment: we can pass unique identifier like ```correlation-id``` in request header and in implementation,  we should send same header back in response so that we can have track for request response.

Comment: @San I thought this way but problem is id should be unique.so how we can pass unique key each time.

Comment: @VikashMishra you can use UUID or GUID. See link - https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see that relation on `client side` where you send request, you can put unique request number into header during request, then let your server take it and put it back to response header to send back to the client.

If you are interested to correlate and log them in server side, then you can use something like `Filter`, `DispatcherServlet` as depending on your needs.